# Getting the previous Word in VBA using selection.previous wdword, 1 bug

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to write a macro to type the previous word at the cursor.
the problem is when i'm using "selection.previous wdword, 1" to get the previous character, it sometimes get the 2 previous characters and it seems like a bug. when i press "delete" button it works and it is very strange to me.
I'd glad if you help.
my ultimate goal is to create a calendar converter inside word using this code.
here is how i test it:

```
MsgBox Selection.previous(unit:=wdWord, Count:=1)
```

it is the same using next :

```
MsgBox Selection.Next(unit:=wdWord, Count:=1)
```

instead of next word, sometimes it returns the word after!

For example this is the text: during the flight on 21/3/1389

If the cursor is right after the 1389, msgbox selection.previous(1,1) would show "/"; if the cursor is after a space after 1389 it shows "1389". The problem is, I think, the space. My question is if there is any alternative to read the previous word instead of this command (Selection.previous(unit:=wdWord, Count:=1))

Comment: Can you give us some examples of text where this is happening? We can't venture an opinion or propose a solution if we can't reproduce what you're seeing...

Comment: for example this is the text:
during the flight on 21/3/1389
if the cursor is right after the 1389, msgbox selection.previous(1,1) would show "/"
if the cursor is after a space after 1389 it shows "1389"
problem is I think the space. if I ask for wdcharacter it works perfectly but word is so buggy :/
my question is if there is any alternative to read the previous word instead of this command (Selection.previous(unit:=wdWord, Count:=1))

Comment: try this: Selection.Next(Unit:=wdWord, Count:=-1)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but it works exactly like .previous version and returns the previous word value.

Answer (score 0):

Word is not buggy - it's behaving as designed. *Something* has to tell Word where words start and end. When the cursor stands to the right of a space it's (quite logically) at the beginning of the next word. So going one word back is going to pick up 1389 instead of /.

You can work around this in your code. I'm sure there's more than one way to do it, but the following works for me in a quick test:

```
Sub GetPrevWord()
  Dim rngSel As word.Range, rngPrev As word.Range

  Set rngSel = Selection.Range
  Set rngPrev = rngSel.Duplicate
  rngPrev.MoveStart wdCharacter, -1
  If Left(rngPrev.Text, 1) = " " Then
    rngPrev.Collapse wdCollapseStart
  End If
  rngPrev.Select
  MsgBox Selection.Previous(unit:=wdWord, Count:=1)
  rngSel.Select
End Sub
```

What it's doing is using two Ranges: one to hold the original selection, the other to work with (`rngPrev`). `rngPrev` is extended backwards by one character and this character is evaluated. If it's a space then `rngPrev` is collapsed to its starting point. (Think of it like pressing the left arrow key of a selection.) In any case, `rngPrev` is selected and your `MsgBox` code is run. Finally, the original range is selected again.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.
I tried it, it worked between to words, but when I tried it at the end of row it returned the 2nd previous word.
i have attached it in the below link.
http://i66.tinypic.com/2n7l5k1.png
I appreciate for more suggestions.

Comment: end of row? You need to be more specific. We also can't provide complete solutions - you need to try some things out for yourself. Figure out what the exceptions are and set up tests. We can show you how to formulate tests, but you need to work out the exceptions...

Comment: sorry I meant end of line. I tried to fix it but it didn't work. I just want to know if there is another alternative for selection.previous word. else i would have to go with character and make my work a bit difficult :/

Comment: by the way if you have a look at the link I attached, you can see the screenshot of my screen. the cursor is at the end of line and it returns the second last word.

Comment: Well, there are also the Range.Move, MoveStart, MoveEnd, MoveWhile, MoveUntil methods that all can work with a Unit (wdWord) and Count. But you're still going to run into the same logical "trap": it all depends on how Word defines "word" and what separates one word from another.